# Redirect domain to an app hosted on Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, cname, ovh

I have a website hosted on Heroku. (let's say : my-app.herokuapp.com)

I bought a domain name on OVH. (let's say : my-domain.com)

I added my-domain.com to domain list on Heroku.

In DNS target, I have my-domain.com.herokudns.com   .

I have to supply this to my DNS provider for the destination of CNAME or ALIAS record.
I did so on OVH. I added :

Subdomain :  www.my-domain.com

TTL: By default

Target : my-domain.com.herokudns.com.      .

But nothing works, I must be missing something. I'm still a beginner with this DNS thing.
In my browser, I have DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN or ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error when I'm trying to access my-domain.com.

It's my first website I'm trying to finish and I will be so happy if somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I waited more than 24h.

Answer (score 1):

You said you created a record for `www.my-domain.com`, but then you are trying to access `my-domain.com`, which is a different hostname. You need to create an ALIAS record for it as well.

Comment: In heroku dashboard, I changed my-domain.com to www.my-domain.com. So the DNS target has changed to Target : www.my-domain.com.herokudns.com. I changed it as well in OVH settings. I will wait 24h and will see if it works, or not ... I created a subdomain (site.my-domain.com) which is redirected to my website (my-app.herokuapp.com), and it works very well ...

Comment: I've the same problem with cpanel, My domaine name provider doesn't support ALIAS , ANAME or FLATTENING records. I shoud use CNAME Record to point my heroku server, But it still not working, please let me know to deal with this issue.